# Conditional stylesheet on Angular Component?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, sass

I have a situation where I have to component that are almost identical, except on 1 variable in the stylesheet. So let's say I have component1's css:

```css
.selector {
    background-color: 'red';
    margin: 12px;
}
```

And component2's css:

```css
.selector {
    background-color: 'red';
}
```

Suppose HTML on both component is the same, as well as the .ts code.
However, there's a ng-content in each and the Is there a way to add the `margin: 12px` is important for component2.

Is there a way, in the component declaration, to have a conditional style, or even stylesheet (in a case where's there's more change than `margin: 12px`, but everything else is the same) ?

Comment: Would `ngClass` work? https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: Not exactly. The thing is, the class is nested in the component, so when I call it, I don't have direct access to it. I might create an @Input() in the root component and get that information, but I only have two cases so this might not be the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about inheritance? Maybe Component2 could extend Component1 but reference a different styleUrl. This way Component2 would have all the logic and variables contained in Component1

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-component-2",
  templateUrl: "./component1.html",
  styleUrls: ["./component2.css"]
})
export class Component2 extends Component1 {}
```